# Integrating GraphQL into NestJS app on microservices

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs, backend

I want to intgrate GraphQL into my project based on microservices architecture.

My API-Gateway module:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiGatewayController } from './api_gateway.controller';
import { ApiGatewayService } from './api_gateway.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import { RmqModule } from '@app/common/rmq/rmq.module';
import {
  MEDIA_SERVICE,
  PROJECT_SERVICE,
  USER_SERVICE,
} from './constants/services';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        MONGODB_URI: Joi.string().required(),
        PORT: Joi.number().required(),
      }),
      envFilePath: './apps/api_gateway/.env',
    }),
    RmqModule.register({
      name: MEDIA_SERVICE,
    }),
    RmqModule.register({
      name: PROJECT_SERVICE,
    }),
    RmqModule.register({
      name: USER_SERVICE,
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [ApiGatewayController],
  providers: [ApiGatewayService],
})
export class ApiGatewayModule {}
```

My Media service (connected to API via RabbitMQ):

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        RABBIT_MQ_URI: Joi.string().required(),
        RABBIT_MQ_MEDIA_QUEUE: Joi.string().required(),
      }),
      envFilePath: './apps/media/.env',
    }),
    DatabaseModule,
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      { name: Video.name, schema: VideoSchema },
      { name: Image.name, schema: ImageSchema },
      { name: Sound.name, schema: SoundSchema },
      { name: Template.name, schema: TemplateSchema },
    ]),
    RmqModule,
  ],
  controllers: [MediaController],
  providers: [
    MediaService,
    VideosRepository,
    SoundsRepository,
    ImagesRepository,
  ],
})
export class MediaModule {}
```

My media schemas separate on 3 (video, sound, image):

```
@Schema({ versionKey: false })
export class Video extends AbstractDocument {
  @Prop({ type: String, enum: Statuses, default: Statuses.NEW })
  status: Statuses;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: TemplateTypes })
  type: TemplateTypes;

  @Prop()
  aspect_ratio: string;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  duration: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  width: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  height: number;

  @Prop()
  file_name: string;

  @Prop()
  mime_type: string;

  @Prop()
  file_id: string;

  @Prop()
  file_unique_id: string;

  @Prop({ default: Date.now() })
  date: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  file_size: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  percentage: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathFile: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathHttp: string;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Template' })
  template: Template;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' })
  project: Project;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  author: User;
}

@Schema({ versionKey: false })
export class Sound extends AbstractDocument {
  @Prop({ type: String, enum: Statuses, default: Statuses.NEW })
  status: Statuses;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: TemplateTypes })
  type: TemplateTypes;

  @Prop()
  file_name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathFile: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathHttp: string;

  @Prop()
  duration: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Template' })
  template: Template;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' })
  project: Project;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  author: User;
}

export const SoundSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Sound);

@Schema({ versionKey: false })
export class Image extends AbstractDocument {
  @Prop({ type: String, enum: Statuses, default: Statuses.NEW })
  status: Statuses;

  @Prop({ type: String, enum: TemplateTypes })
  type: TemplateTypes;

  @Prop()
  file_name: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathFile: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  pathHttp: string;

  @Prop({ default: 5 })
  duration: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  width: number;

  @Prop({ default: 0 })
  height: number;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Template' })
  template: Template;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' })
  project: Project;

  @Prop({ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' })
  author: User;
}

export const ImageSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Image);
```

To use GraphQL queries based on these schemas i need to generate types correctly. How integrate GraphQL in situation, when my schemas separate on many microservices, but all requests sending to API-Gateway?

I try to integrate GraphQL by docs, but its not working. Maybe im not understand how.